# Saving a Single User Setting in C#

Tags: c#, settings

I am working on implementing the saving of User Settings in my .NET C# application, and in one case I would like to only save a single setting.  Is it possible to do that, or is my only option to save all User Settings at once with the standard:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Comment: You could have the object that the user edits be a different one than `Properties.Settings.Default`, and only transfer the setting that you want saved from your object into that one before calling `Save()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use [NINI](http://nini.sourceforge.net/), and store an XML configuration file in someplace like `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`.

Might not be quite as easy as the .NET settings stuff. I never really used them anyway.

For example, I have the class below. All I need to do it get or set the properties, and they're automatically loaded/saved:

```
using Nini.Config;

public class DbConfig : PropertyNotifierBase {
    private static readonly string PROGRAM_NAME = "programname";
    private static readonly string CONFIG_NAME = "Database";

    private static DbConfig _instance = new DbConfig();

    public static DbConfig Instance { get { return (_instance); } }

    private DbConfig() {
        SetupPaths();
        Source = new XmlConfigSource(FullConfigFilename);
        Source.AutoSave = true;
        CreateSectionsIfNeeded();
    }

    private void CreateSectionsIfNeeded() {
        if (Source.Configs["Database"] == null)
            Source.AddConfig("Database");
    }

    private void SetupPaths() {
        ConfigPath = DetermineConfigPath();
        ConfigFilename = String.Format("{0}.xml", CONFIG_NAME);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(ConfigPath);

        // Create an empty configuration file if it isn't there.
        if (!File.Exists(FullConfigFilename))
            File.WriteAllText(FullConfigFilename, "<Nini>\n</Nini>\n");
    }

    private IConfigSource Source { get; set; }

    public String ConfigPath { get; private set; }

    public String ConfigFilename { get; private set; }

    public String FullConfigFilename { get { return (Path.Combine(ConfigPath, ConfigFilename)); } }

    public String SqlServerInstance {
        get { return (Source.Configs["Database"].GetString("SqlServerInstance", @"somedefaultconnection")); }
        set { Source.Configs["Database"].Set("SqlServerInstance", value); NotifyPropertyChanged("SqlServerInstance"); }
    }

    public String SqlServerDatabase {
        get { return (Source.Configs["Database"].GetString("SqlServerDatabase", "somedatabasename")); }
        set { Source.Configs["Database"].Set("SqlServerDatabase", value); NotifyPropertyChanged("SqlServerDatabase"); }
    }

    public String SqlServerUsername {
        get { return (Source.Configs["Database"].GetString("SqlServerUsername", "someusername")); }
        set { Source.Configs["Database"].Set("SqlServerUsername", value); NotifyPropertyChanged("SqlServerUsername"); }
    }

    public String SqlServerPassword {
        get { return (Source.Configs["Database"].GetString("SqlServerPassword", "somepassword")); }
        set { Source.Configs["Database"].Set("SqlServerPassword", value); NotifyPropertyChanged("SqlServerPassword"); }
    }

    private string DetermineConfigPath() {
        String filename = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
        filename += Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + PROGRAM_NAME;
        return (filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: Steve, can you give an example of how you would do this?  I am somewhat of a beginner.

Comment: I just made an edit and posted a class I use. It's very easy. Including a reference to the NINI DLL, and that little bit of code up there, it all that's needed.

Comment: By the way, in that class I'm saving connection information for a database connection, and the password is saved in cleartext. Not very secure, but for my application, not a concern to me.